# :nth-child(1) not working - with html sample

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Why would this rule;

```
.ss-form-fields:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color: red;}
```

.. not work with this markup ...

[image]

The first 2 divs are causing it to fail - in fact none of the 4 divs present are effected but it.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: `.ss-form-fields` is not the first element of it's type within that container

Comment: So can you say how I would target the .ss-form-fields element (first)?

Comment: It's not the first element of it's type And it's not the first child, it's the second.

Comment: So can you help?

Comment: Change `1` to `2`